# conditional custom attribut directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two custom directives (restrict : 'A') which are working well (custom1 and custom2)

In my html page I would like to use either custom1 attribut or custom2 attribut on a div depending on a condition. For example I would like to write something like this :

```
<div condition?custom1:custom2 />
```

I don't want to use ng-if like in the following code:

```
<div id='main-div' ng-if="map.2d==true" custom1 />
<div id='main-div' ng-if="map.2d==false" custom2 />
```

Is there a way to write such a condition for attribut custom directives?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

You could build a separate directive which dynamically compiles the required directive:

```
app.directive('dynamicDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      dynamicDirective: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var e = $compile("<div " + scope.dynamicDirective + "></div>")(scope);
      elem.append(e);
    }
  };
});
```

It can be used as follows (in this sample `someDirective` is defined on the scope and has the name of the required directive):

```
<div dynamic-directive="someDirective"></div>
```

[Here is a sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/u5moX3RkRavX8gqFlc7J?p=preview)

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax ? It seems that it's not working. But anyway I would like to use a 'A' directive since it's not a css style that I want to 'inject' but a real behaviour on my html element.

Comment: @clement you are right it doesn't work as the interpolation runs after the directive compilation. I will update my answer.